# JQuery AddMethod validation add field access special character & and modify @ special character

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am new for **JQuery addmethod validation**. So I want to validate a field in create page access & special character and modify access `@` special character .

My code like working only create page need modify page:

```
$("validator").addMethod("spchar",function (value,element)
{
    return this.oprional(element)||/^[0-9a-zA-Z_&.,]+$/i.test(value);
}, "not allow"

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to require Special characters in this field?  If so this is what I did to achieve that method.

```
        jQuery.validator.addMethod(
        'ContainsAtLeastOneSpecialCharacter',
        function (value) {
            return /\W/.test(value);
        },
        'Your [fieldname] must contain at least one special character.'
    );
```

Where fieldname is a variable. I used this for a password field.
Hope that helps.